# Property of continuous maps from $S^3$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p=e^{2\pi i/m}$ for some integer $m>1$. If $f:S^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous map, prove that $\sum_{k=1}^mp^{-k}f(p^kz_1,p^kz_2)=0$ for some point $(z_1,z_2)\in S^3$.

In class we have just learned the Borusk-Ulam theorem for maps from $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. I also have access to the following fact. There exist no continuous maps $g:S^3\rightarrow S^1$ such that $g(pz_1,pz_2)=pg(z_1,z_2)$ for all $(z_1,z_2)\in S^3$.

I'm just not seeing how to deconstruct this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call your map $g$ (you mean to sum over k, not i). Is it clear that $g(pz,pw) = p g(z,w)$? If $g$ was always nonzero, then consider the map $h(z,w) = g(z,w)/|g(z,w)|$. This is a map to the circle with $h(pz,pw) = ph(z,w)$. Contradiction

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Don't forget that this website is intended for people to ask for *help*: telling someone "this should come naturally to you" is not always helpful (if it came naturally to them, they probably wouldn't be asking for help). I think your answer would get a better reaction from the community if you removed this sentence, and fixed your spelling mistakes. Your answer does appear to be correct, it just comes off as a bit rude.

Comment: @William I am interested in people getting better at math, not just telling them the answers. It is ridiculous that you removed this sentence.

Comment: In retrospect this answer should not have been posted because a small hint would have been more suitable but I do not think I can delete

Comment: It's ok (and even good) to not spoonfeed a complete answer to people, in fact it's common for people to post an "answer" which is just helpful hints, and leave it up to OP to fill in the blanks themselves. This is a perfectly acceptable and sometimes popular form of answer. For the record I did not down-vote your answer, and I also didn't remove the statement in question.